# Not understanding "variable length" in PL/.SQL

Tags: plsql

See the excerpt below taken from a PL/SQL tutorial. The part I have an issue with is line 3, where it says salary is of length 6. I don't understand what that means. In the last line of this excerpt, it declares a variable "of length 10" which is then initialized to "HR Dept" which is certainly not 10 characters. What is meant by length?

---

```
DECLARE

salary  number (6);

* “salary” is a variable of datatype number and of length 6.
```

When a variable is specified as NOT NULL, you must initialize the variable when it is declared.

For example: The below example declares two variables, one of which is a not null.

```
DECLARE

salary number(4);

dept varchar2(10) NOT NULL := “HR Dept”;
```

---

Another example:

```
DECLARE 



var_salary number(6); 

 var_emp_id number(6) = 1116;
```

1116 is not 6 digits. I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Maximum* length. You'd discover this if you tried to store eleven characters into `dept` or if you started making a cool million each year at whatever your job is.

It's no different from when you create tables:

```
create table users (
    id     integer,
    name   varchar(20)
);
```

In that case, `20` is the maximum length of the name. It doesn't mean every row has to have a 20-character name.

Comment: HOLY @#*#$) 196K DUDE WHAT ARE YOU?

Answer (score 3):

These are the *maximum* "length" of the data. From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#i54330), here's the exact meaning for number:

> **`NUMBER [ (p [, s]) ]`**
>
> Number having precision p and scale s. The precision p can range from
>   1 to 38. The scale s can range from -84 to 127. Both precision and
>   scale are in decimal digits. A NUMBER value requires from 1 to 22
>   bytes.

A variable of type `NUMBER(6)` can store any number from -999999 to 999999.

And for VARCHAR2:

> **`VARCHAR2(size [BYTE | CHAR])`**
>
> Variable-length character string having
>   maximum length size bytes or characters. Maximum size is 4000 bytes or
>   characters, and minimum is 1 byte or 1 character. You must specify
>   size for VARCHAR2. BYTE indicates that the column will have byte
>   length semantics. CHAR indicates that the column will have character
>   semantics.

A VARCHAR2(10) can store up to 10 bytes or 10 characters (depending upon the parameter `nls_length_semantics`).

Answer (score 0):

In oracle, the length of a number variable is the maximum number of digits it can hold. For your case , you can have numbers between -99999 to 999999